# Square Integrable Process Implication

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

In Sergii Kuchuk and Yuliya Mishura paper, Pricing the European Call Option in the Model with Stochastic Volatility Driven by Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process, Exact Formulas, the model can be represented by
$$ dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma(Y_t) S_t dB_t $$
$$ dY_t = -\alpha Y_t dt + k dW_t $$
One of the assumptions in the paper is the volatility function $ \sigma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+ $ is measureable and bounded away from zero by a constant $ c $ and satisfies the conditions $ \int_{0}^{T} \sigma^2(Y_t) dt < \infty $. Later it is said that given the square integrability of $ \sigma(Y_s) $ the solution of the first equation of the model is
$$ S_t = S_0 exp \bigg{(} \mu t - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma^2(Y_S) ds + \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(Y_s) dB_s \bigg{)} $$

**Question**

1. Does the statement "given the square integrability of $ \sigma(Y_s) $" imply $ \int_{0}^{T} \sigma^2(Y_t) dt < \infty $? I know that $ \sigma(Y_s) $ is square integrable if $ \mathbb{E} \big{(} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(Y_s)^2 ds \big{)} < \infty $. Can we imply if $ \mathbb{E} \big{(} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(Y_s)^2 ds \big{)} < \infty $ then $ \int_{0}^{T} \sigma^2(Y_t) dt < \infty $?
2. Why $ \sigma $ should be bounded away from zero?

Comment: For the first ignoring abuse of language the square integrability only means by definition $\int_{0}^{T} \sigma^2(Y_t) dt < \infty$ i.e. for any path $\omega$ this is true. This is a sufficient conditon for the existence of the stochastic integral $ \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(Y_s) dB_s$. No need to interpret this further. Regards